Is there a way to correct a wooden archery bow that was bent in the wrong direction for a long time
I recently bought a Ben Pearson Mustang at a junk sale. I'm new to archery and was hoping to make it my first cheap, usable bow. Judging by the logo, I think it's from the 70's.
Upon further examination when I got home, I noticed that the bow had been strung backwards. I was able to get the string off of it but the bow is maintaining it's reversed shape.
Is there a way of making this bow usable again? I'd like to train on it at least.

Are you sure it is reversed - being new to archery you might be missing something. It could be a recurve bow for instance. It is highly unlikely that anyone would string a bow backwards as it would be against the natural shape of the bow. Take it to a local archery club...

Get Yourself acquainted with what a recurve bow is. Then get a month of training from a professional. And only then judge the body & string and on "not sure" throw it in the garbage as eye implants don't come cheap.
